# Copy Shapes in Flowchart from Dia to Excel

Tags: export, export-to-excel, diagram, flowchart, dia

Could we copy Shapes in Flowchart from Dia to Excel or Word to edit them? and how to do that. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a pity! As I know, we can't copy shapes in flowchart from Dia to Excel or Word. So I did flowchart using Word (Excel) to able to copy and edit the shape easily.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following: Create a diagram with a single shape and export it in EMF or WMF format. EMF/WMF formats can be read as graphics in Word/Excel

Comment: Editing of the EMF/WMF will be quite limited. You could do all the necessary editing before you export/import. You may also try to "explode" the graphic in Word/Excel